# How to find length of an integer in JSP?

Tags: string, jsp, jstl, int

I can use `fn:length(mystring)` to find the length/number of character of a string.

How can I find the length/number of digits in an integer?

e.g. if my int is 3000, I want to return 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to `String` first by evaluating it as body of [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html):

```
<c:set var="intAsString">${someInt}</c:set>
```

Then you can get its length the usual way:

```
${fn:length(intAsString)}
```