# Difference between specifying JSTL <c:set> value via attribute and body

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to figure out if there's any functional difference between these two uses of the JSTL `<c:set>` tag. Let's assume I have imported some string constants into my JSP page via something like:

```
<%@ page import="some.package.of.AppConstants"%>
```

So, given the above import directive, what's the difference between these two examples:

1. Specifying the value in `value` attribute:

   ```
   <c:set var="SOME_VAR" value="${AppConstants.SOME_CONSTANT}" />
   ```
2. Specifying the value in tag body:

   ```
   <c:set var="SOME_VAR">
       <%=AppConstants.SOME_CONSTANT%>
   </c:set>
   ```

Is there any difference in what the value of `${SOME_VAR}` will be in the second example versus the first example? Would the presence of any special characters in `AppConstants.SOME_CONSTANT` affect the value of `${SOME_VAR}` in either of these cases?

Answer (score 4):

> *Difference between jstl c:set value in attribute and body of tag*

There **is** a technical difference.

The `value` keeps the original value type. E.g., if you supplied `Integer` or whatever, it will stay `Integer`. The body, however, basically does a `toString()` on the value and thus essentially converts any type to `String`. This can be beneficial in some cases, e.g.:

- [Convert integer value to string using JSTL/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576131/convert-integer-value-to-string-using-jstl-el/)
- [How to find length of an integer in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343203/how-to-find-length-of-an-integer-in-jsp/)
- [How to check isNumeric/IsNumber in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008298/how-to-check-isnumeric-isnumber-in-jstl/)
- [how to get the base url from jsp request object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271075/how-to-get-the-base-url-from-jsp-request-object)

---

Coming back to the concrete functional requirement, the first example will only work if you're targeting a Servlet 3.1 / EL 3.0 container (Tomcat 8, etc) with a webapp whose `web.xml` matches Servlet 3.1.

```
<c:set var="SOME_VAR" value="${AppConstants.SOME_CONSTANT}" />
```

Namely, this is only supported since EL 3.0. This is definitely the preferred approach over the *Scriptlet* way. You should try to avoid *Scriptlets* at all cost. You only need to keep in mind that the code is not backwards compatible with older versioned target runtimes.

#### See also:

- [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/)

Answer (score 1):

According to O'Reillys [HeadsFirstServlets](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/) pg 457, why would you use the body version of c:set instead of the no-body version. It looks like they do the same thing.

Answer:

> That’s because they DO... do the
>   same thing. The body version is just for
>   convenience when you want more room for
>   the value. It might be a long and complex
>   expression, for example, and putting it in
>   the body makes it easier to read.

*Update*

After some additional research it turns out the above reasoning pertains only to EL v2.2 and lower. See the answer by BalusC for 3.0 behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turns out my prob was not related to using an attribute versus body to assign the value. I finally figured out that the key difference was in the way I was assigning the values, using an expression in the first example and a scriptlet in the 2nd example. It turns out that in Expression Language 2.x, imported class/interface are not in scope and therefore can't be referenced using EL (eg: ${AppConstants.SOME_CONSTANT}). They must instead be referenced via a scriptlet. I'm voting up your reply anyway because you were the only person who tried to answer constructively